# How to Access to XMLHttpRequest in Angular

Tags: javascript, php, angular

How to allow XMLHttpRequest in angular. 
because I have getData.php

and the error is
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8888/*****/****/getData.php' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem doesn't come from your js, but from your server which doesn't allow CORS request (request from another server). (even thought your request come from `localhost` to `localhost` since the ports are different they are considered 2 differents server)

You'll need to allow CORS request using the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in your http requests

more details [on this answer from apsillers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work/10636765#10636765)(don't forget to upvote him if it solved the problem)

Comment: I already import httpclient in my global.service.ts and I use Global Service

Comment: @ABC since you didn't talk about it I couldn't know, removed the part about it

Comment: In my global.service.ts - ```headers = {
      'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Access-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token'}```

Comment: @ABC you need to add these header server-side

Comment: in the server.ts?

Comment: @ABC in the php script, using [the header function](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.header.php)

Comment: in my ```executeTask.php``` I already put ```<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Encoding: gzip, deflate");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token");
    include 'config.php';

    $taskName = $_REQUEST['taskName'];

    $array = array();
    $subArray=array();```

Comment: in ```getData.php``` here's the code ```<?php

include 'config.php';

$sel = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `temperaturedata`ORDER BY dateandtime asc LIMIT 5 ");
$data = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sel)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($data);


```

Comment: @ABC I think you should also have all the header calls in `getData.php` or include`executeTask.php` in it, your browser is looking for `getData` so it don't care about the content of `executeTask` unless you explicitely include it somewhere

Comment: @ABC then I don't know I'm sorry

Comment: if i add the header() should it needed to call or doesn't need to call it?

Comment: ```Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8888/templogger/services/getData.php' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199061/discussion-between-jonatjano-and-abc).